# PHP String: remove "\newline" after "\end{Figure}"

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I've PHP String of around 4000 chars; if anywhere in this PHP string $input1, $input2 or $input3 is identified, I want to replace same with $output string. In Summary I want to remove "\newline" after "\end{Figure}"

```
$input1 = "\end{Figure}\newline";
$input2 = "\end{Figure} \newline";
$input3 = "\end{Figure}\newline "

Required output: 
$output = "\end{Figure}";
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\\\end\{Figure}\K( )?\\\newline(?(1)| )~', '', $text);
```

pattern details:

```
~                # pattern delimiter
\\\              # backslash (must be double escaped inside quotes)
end\{Figure}
\K               # reset the begining of the match
( )?             # optional capturing group n°1
\\\newline
(?(1)| )         # if capturing group n°1 exists there is nothing else a space 
~
```

Comment: Thanks for giving breakup of pattern; this is very much useful